# CUDA: embedded for loop kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some code that I want to make into a cuda kernel. Behold:

```
    for (r = Y; r < Y + H; r+=2)
    {
        ch1RowSum = ch2RowSum = ch3RowSum = 0;
        for (c = X; c < X + W; c+=2)
        {
            chan1Value = //some calc'd value
                            chan3Value = //some calc'd value
            chan2Value = //some calc'd value
            ch2RowSum  += chan2Value;
            ch3RowSum  += chan3Value;
            ch1RowSum  += chan1Value;
        }
        ch1Mean += ch1RowSum / W;
        ch2Mean += ch2RowSum / W;
        ch3Mean += ch3RowSum / W;
    }
```

Should this be split up into two kernels, one to calculate the RowSums and one to calculate the Means, and how should I handle the fact that my loop indices dont start at zero and end at N?

Comment: try to choose one question, it makes it hard to select a correct answer. but, as to your second question... it's hard to answer specifically, but I think you will see once you get farther along developing your kernel.

Comment: you ought to launch your kernel with a configuration like H blocks and W threads per block. Then, you will calculate r and c from the blockIdx and threadIdx values inside the kernel. calculate r and c however you want... i tried to put this in my answer below...

Comment: It did seem like two questions, but i wasnt sure the context would be there if i tried to write it as two questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a kernel that computes the three values. Each thread in your configuration will compute the three values for each (r,c) pair.

```
__global__ value_kernel(Y, H, X, W)
{
    r = blockIdx.x + Y;
    c = threadIdx.x + W;

    chan1value = ...
    chan2value = ...
    chan3value = ...
}
```

I don't believe you can calculate the sum (completely in parallel, at least) in the above kernel. You won't be able to use += like you have above. You could put it all in one kernel if you have only one thread in each block (row) do the sum and mean, like this...

```
__global__ both_kernel(Y, H, X, W)
{
    r = blockIdx.x + Y;
    c = threadIdx.x + W;

    chan1value = ...
    chan2value = ...
    chan3value = ...

    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        ch1RowSum = 0;
        ch2RowSum = 0;
        ch3RowSum = 0;

        for(i=0; i<blockDim.x; i++)
        {
            ch1RowSum += chan1value;
            ch2RowSum += chan2value;
            ch3RowSum += chan3value;
        }

        ch1Mean = ch1RowSum / blockDim.x;
        ch2Mean = ch2RowSum / blockDim.x;
        ch3Mean = ch3RowSum / blockDim.x;
    }
}
```

but it's probably better to use the first value kernel and then a second kernel for both sums and means... It's possible to further parallelize the kernel below, and if it's separate you can focus on that when you're ready.

```
__global__ sum_kernel(Y,W)
{
    r = blockIdx.x + Y;

    ch1RowSum = 0;
    ch2RowSum = 0;
    ch3RowSum = 0;

    for(i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        ch1RowSum += chan1value;
        ch2RowSum += chan2value;
        ch3RowSum += chan3value;
    }

    ch1Mean = ch1RowSum / W;
    ch2Mean = ch2RowSum / W;
    ch3Mean = ch3RowSum / W;
}
```

Comment: i mentioned that you can parallelize the sum/mean... what you want is a reduction. (one of many available examples: http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/cuda-tutorial-3-thread-communication/)

Comment: I notice that you didnt actually use the values of R or C here. Should there be some sort of check to do a No Op if like blockIdx.x*threadIdx.x is greater than blockIdx.x+Y? what would that look like exactly?

Comment: you didn't use r or c in your code, either. You have three values that are calculated for each grid location (r,c). You will probably want to have one thread calculate one set of values. When you launch your kernel, launch with r blocks and c threads per block. Then, in each thread you can calculate r and c from the block id and thread id. I assume r and c are used to access input for the value calculations and/or they are used directly. (if you might launch a kernel with more threads or blocks than you need, then sure check your bounds... something like if(r >= #rows || c >= #cols) return;)

Comment: in general, it sounds to me like you need to read more about how to use CUDA, or look at some examples. what is the input? how will you get the data on to the gpu? how will it be arranged? how will you access it? how wil the results be arranged? how will you get the results back to the cpu? try to get all of this working with just the value computations and compare them with cpu computed values first.